# placeholder in cakephp 3.X

Tags: html, attributes, cakephp-3.0

I have a placeholder in text field which is not working ( given below)

```
  <?php echo $this->Form->input('county', [
    'type' => 'text', 
    'placeholder' => 'Enter county', 
    'autocomplete' => 'off', 
    'label' => false, 
    'div' => false, 
    'id' => 'adv_county']
 );?>
```

Comment: that should work, do you have other javascript or CSS that could prevent the placeholder text to be shown?

Comment: I tried your code and it works. Even if in cake3 `input` is deprecated and you should use `control`.